# Passing DatagridView Selected value to an open form without opening new form

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Hi I have a form called `service_reservation`. When I click a button in it, I get a form with a datagridview without closing `service_reservation` form. What I want is to pass a selected value from data grid view to the open `service_reservation` form, without opening new form.

```
Private Sub DataGridView_CellClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
    Dim i As Integer
    i = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index
    If i >= 0 Then
        Service_Reservation.txtBoxSerID.Text = DataGridView1.Item(0, i).Value
        Service_Reservation.Show()
        Me.Close()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Empty Row Clicked")
    End If
End Sub
```

But above code displays new `service_reservation` form. Please help

Comment: If you use `hide` and `show`, you will not create new instance. Just keep reference to instance somewhere. An have a property where you want to pass value. Set property and call `show`. It is not really clear what opens what. But seems you confusing `Close` and `Hide`

Answer (score -1):

```
Private Sub DataGridView_CellClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As 
 System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
    Dim i As Integer
    i = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index
    If i >= 0 Then
        Service_Reservation.Show()  
        Service_Reservation.txtBoxSerID.Text = DataGridView1.Item(0, i).Value
        Me.Close()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Empty Row Clicked")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please provide a short explanation as to why you think this is the user's desired solution.